# Unit test for a method that calls an API in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

So I trying to make unit tests for an API Post call that calls another API, the code looks somewhat like this:

```
public class ConfigController : ControllerBase
{
  ...
   [HttpPost("GetValue")]
   public async Result MainMethod(int id){
    ...
    response = MakeApiCall(id)
    ...
    return response.value + some stuff
   }


   public async Result MakeApiCall(int id){
   return GetAsync(otherAPIurl/id={id});
   }
 }
```

When writing a unit test, I want to test the MainMethod but without relying on the response of the other API, this way if the other API causes a problem, these tests will still work and I know the fails won't be related to my code, I know I am supposed to use mocks, but I dont now how to in this context where the main method directly calls the other. ChatGPT keeps telling me to make some interfaces and classes and it all ends up in BS everytime.

Comment: You are supposed to make some interfaces and classes, more specifically make an interface that has the `MakeApiCall` method on it, implement it for your application and register the interface and the implementation in your DI container. Then, for your test, mock the interface and inject that mock instead.

Comment: Thanks @MindSwipe that worked like a charm, I think thats what chatgpt was going for lol

Answer (score 1):

If HttpClient based, use mockhttp: https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp